# How can I incorporate a RTF doc into a SwiftUI View?

Tags: swiftui, rtf

I want to be able to create and edit a RTF doc for read-only information via Xcode (or external word processor) and display it within a SwiftUI view rather than to code a string piecemeal with in-line format directives.

The closest way of doing this is via **NSAttributedString** which can incorporate the rtf doc.

Is there a more-modern approach?

Comment: Did you found a way to do this?

Comment: I don't believe I did; beyond using NSAttributedString.

Comment: I understand, I will go a similar way, thank you.